# Заполнить ячейки диапазонами номеров с шагом

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Нужно заполнить ячейки столбца по следующему шаблону:

`1 5
 6 10
 11 15`

и т.д.'

- первое число первой ячейки  - 1 (единица);
- для всех диапазонов одинаковый шаг (в примере шаг = 5);
- первое число следующей ячейки = последнее число предыдущей + 1
- между числами обязательно пробел.

Как можно это сделать с помощью маски для автозаполнения или формулы?

Comment: Задача непонтна. Уточните. Опишите более развернут. Заполнять из другой программы? Все в одной яейке или по строкам, столбцам? Как меняется разница?

Comment: заполняю руками. по строкам (как в вопросе). Разница меняется рандомно, ее нужно задавать в самой маске. т.е. должна быть какая-то мака, которая при растяжении вниз заполняет мне таким образом нужное количество ячеек. Пусть будут, допустим, номера квартир по этажам (для понимания ТЗ)

Comment: Задача понятна. Нужно нажать данные - проверка данных - тип проверки - другой, формула. Может быть найдётся кто-нибудь кто вместо вас сочинит формулу.

Comment: А мне непонятна... Номера квартир по этажам - какая же здесь случайность? Покажите пример в файле (в крайнем случае - иллюстрацию исходных данных и резльтата).

Comment: количество квартир на этаже может быть разным. Это не единичная задача. Пример есть в вопросе

Comment: Посмотрите - уже 3 голоса за закрытие Вашего вопроса. Нужно описывать доходчиво. Ваш "пример" - не пример. Количество кваритир разное - как случайая величина узнает, какой ей быть? На этаже 5 квартир, а Вам выдаст число 15

Comment: должен быть какой-то способ задать шаг (нач.значение +" "+конечн.значение) как-то так... и эту маску растянуть на нужное количество ячеек. Так нельзя сделать? проблема в том, что не увеличивается число после пробела.`1 5
6 5
11 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В *A1* - шаг

Формула для диапазона:

```
=(СТРОКА(A1)-1)*$A$1+1&" "&СТРОКА(A1)*$A$1
```